# What are all the extras?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-1.5-remix

What are all the extras listed on the main menu screen (the game selection screen) and how do I get them? I got the 358/2 theme already, but how do I get the other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [gameFAQS](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/684080-kingdom-hearts-hd-15-remix/cheats):

> ```
> Unlockable                            How to Unlock
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days             Obtain 358/2 Days Master Trophy
> Kingdom Hearts Final Mix Theme        Complete Kingdom Hearts Final Mix
> Kingdom Hearts Re: Chain of Memories  Complete Kingdom Hearts Re: Chain of Memories
> ```

To get the other two, you need to complete the respective games that the themes are from.